# Calculus show that the function $F(x)$ has the value $(a+b)/2$

Tags: calculus

Show that the function $F(x)=(x-a)^2(x-b)^2+x$ has the value $(a+b)/2$ as some point $x$.

I have heard that $F(a)=a$ and $F(b)=b$ and that I should take some kind of average. But I do not understand why that is. I have also heard that $(a+b)/2$ is the average of the two values which is simple but I do not understand why that is important.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that $a<b$. Then $a <(a+b)/2<b$. Since $F(a)=a$ and $F(b)=b$ and $F$ is continuous, the intermediate value theorem says: there is $t \in (a,b)$ such that $F(t)=(a+b)/2$.

Its your turn to investigate the situations $b<a$ and $a=b$.